# C# .NET Regex problem

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to find out a solution to an issue I'm having. If I execute the following C# code:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[\\r\\n]*");
Match m = r.Match("\\r\\n");
```

If I examine the value of `m.Success`, I get a value of true, which is correct. But if I examine the value of `m.Length`, I get a value of `0`. If I examine `m.Value`, I also get a blank value. Am I missing something in my Regex? I am under the impression that either `m.Success` needs to be false and `m.Length` is 0 or else `m.Success` needs to be true and `m.Length` needs to be greater then 0. Any help on clearifing this would be appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't the second line be `Match m = r.Match("\r\n");` ? I imagine this is a string with actual cr/lf chars, not escaped ?

Comment: if you leave out one '\', it does do the job... But I do not know if that is what is intended...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match.Success returns true because the Regex is supposed to match "zero or more" instances of "\r" or "\n", that is, carriage return or line feed, (as indicated by the "*" symbol). However, the string you gave (within Match) instead contains backslash, r, backslash, n, which is neither a carriage return nor a line feed, so the length of the match was zero. (Within the regular expression, the "backslash, n" is treated as a single character, line feed).

To avoid further confusion in the future, try prefixing the regular expression with an "@" symbol to possibly avoid some confusion with how the backslashes work in regular expressions, like this:

```
 @"[\r\n]*"
```

Hopefully this makes it a little clearer that "\r" stands for a carriage return and "\n" for a line feed. The related regular expression:

```
 @"[\\rn]*"
```

Would match zero or more instances of backslashes, r, and/or n. (The doubled backslash is necessary because that symbol is treated specially in regular expressions.)

Comment: Such a frickin' obvious mistake on my part. Thanks Peter